# How to request a microsoft azure resource using a access token? In short how can we use the generated access_token in azure?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-active-directory

I have registered an app in Azure. I can get `access_token` from **oauth2/v2.0/token** from password grant. I can also get `refresh_token` from **oauth2/v2.0/token** using refresh_token grant
**But, How do I request a resource in Microsoft Azure using an `access_token`?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

***In short how can we use the generated access_token in azure?***

> When you would request anything on azure you have to pass your access
>   token as your request header`request.Headers.Authorization` which is
>   `Bearer` token.

- Here I am giving you an example how you could access azure resource using your access token.

```cs
    //New Block For Accessing Data from Microsoft Graph Rest API
    HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
    HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users"));
    //Passing Token For this Request
    request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Pass Your Token Here");
    HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
    //Get User List From Response 
    dynamic objGpraphUserList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

> I am accessing [`Azure Active Directory User List`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-list?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)  using `access token`. I got this response
>
> See the screenshot below:

[image]

***Azure Resource API Access Sample :***

As Per [Gaurav Mantri's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/188096/gaurav-mantri) Recommendation I am also giving you another example how you could get azure resource group information. See below code snippet

```cs
            //How You Would Request Microsft Resource Management API For Resources List 
            var  azureSubcriptionId = "Your_Azure_Subcription_Id";
            var resourceGroupName = "Your_Resource_Group_Name";
            HttpClient _client = new HttpClient();
            HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, string.Format("https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{0}/resourceGroups/{1}/resources?api-version=2019-10-01", azureSubcriptionId, resourceGroupName));
            //Passing Token For this Request
            request.Headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", "Pass Your Token Here");
            HttpResponseMessage response = await _client.SendAsync(request);
            //Get User List From Response 
            dynamic objAzureResourceGroupList = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<dynamic>(await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync());
```

Also Tested on PostMan.

[image]

For more details you could refer [Official Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/resources/resources/list)

Hope this would help you.

Comment: Yeah @GauravMantri I seen , as he is using `ROPC` which is not recommended that's why given him full example. By the way I have also included how he can Request using that. Is am I okay?

Comment: Please feel free to keep the post. It might be helpful to others. I just found the answer a bit irrelevant to the question, that’s all.

Comment: I have updated my answer as per your suggestion. Thanks for the comment.

Comment: Can you please edit your question and include an example to access an Azure Resource (e.g. List Resource Group)?

Comment: Okay updating with that one. Thanks once again.

Answer (score 0):

This process has been defined very clearly here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure. Especially look at the section titled [`Create the request`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/#create-the-request) which will tell you exactly what needs to be done.